# Can't Get address using Longitude & Latitude Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I am trying to get address from longitude and latitude but unable to get the address. I am getting Longi. and lati. value but when I pass it to the function of getAddress it stop working Kindly help me if you guys can.
Here is my Code

**MainActivity.java File**

```
package com.example.mygps;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnGet;
    GPS_Class gps;
    TextView adr,cty,ctry;

    double longi, lati;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnGet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
        adr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.adr);
        cty = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cty);
        ctry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ctry);

        btnGet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                gps = new GPS_Class(MainActivity.this);
                if(gps.canGetLocation())
                {

                    longi = gps.getLongitude();
                    lati = gps.getLatitude();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Longitude is:"+longi+"Latidute is:"+lati, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    getAddress(longi, lati);
                }
                else
                {
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();

                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void getAddress(double longitude, double latitude)
    {
        double long1,lati1;
        long1 = longitude;
        lati1 = latitude;
        if(lati>0 && long1>0)
        {
        Geocoder geocode = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;

        try {
            addresses = geocode.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 1);

            String Addres_ = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String Country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            String City = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

            adr.setText(Addres_);
            cty.setText(City);
            ctry.setText(Country);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }//if closing. . . 
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Vlaue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
}
```

**My GPS_Class.java File Code**

```
package com.example.mygps;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;

public class GPS_Class extends Service implements LocationListener{



    //To Get Context of the class...
    Context context;

    //Declaring Variable to use. . .
    double lattitude;
    double longitude;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetWorkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    //Declaring objects of different classes...
    Location location;
    LocationManager locationmanager;

    public GPS_Class(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        GetLocation();
    }

    //Self Coded Function to perform all location works . . .
    private Location GetLocation()
    {
        locationmanager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);  

        isGPSEnabled = locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetWorkEnabled = locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(isNetWorkEnabled)
        {
            canGetLocation = true;
            locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,this);

            if(locationmanager !=null)
            {
                location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if(location !=null)
                {
                    lattitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                }
            }
        }

        if(isGPSEnabled)
        {
            canGetLocation = true;
            if(location == null)
            {
            locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,this);
            if(locationmanager != null)
            {
                location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                if(location!=null)
                {
                    lattitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                }
            }
        }
        }

        return location;
    }

     public void showSettingsAlert(){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

            // On pressing Settings button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            // on pressing cancel button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }


     public double getLatitude(){
            if(location != null){
                lattitude = location.getLatitude();
            }

            // return latitude
            return lattitude;
        }

    public double getLongitude()
    {
        if(location !=null)
        {
        longitude =location.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by **stop working** here?

Comment: @Rehan if I will comment the getAddress(); function it will give me Longi. And lati. But if I will uncomment the function my app stops working.

Comment: What actually happens? The app crashes or gets into not responding state? Or by stop working you mean it is not working as per your expectations?

Comment: App crashes by saying unfortunately app not working or something like that.

Comment: Post your **LogCat** then

Comment: Not enough speed to share logcat. But...I Think I am not getting values of longi. And lati in getAddress() funtion thats why it shows "No Value" Toast or app crashes if i remove If else from the function.

Comment: Then I would suggest you to use [GoogleApiClient](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) to get current location.

Comment: here is logcat pic http://i.imgur.com/KGsC7DK.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got Solution**
The Above mention posted code is fine It can get the current location.
If you will try to run it on emulator it will show you error because "Geocoder" class is not compatible with Emulator.
Run it on Device it is Working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try with changing `this` with `MainActivity.this` in `getAddress` method:

```
Geocoder geocode = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
```

`getFromLocation` method Throws. So check your latitude value. It is not in correct range:

```
IllegalArgumentException    if latitude is less than -90 or greater than 90

IllegalArgumentException    if longitude is less than -180 or greater than 180

IOException if the network is unavailable or any other I/O problem occurs
```

Comment: Just app stops with that Unfortunately app not working.

Comment: Sorry sir but Internet speed is not enough to post logcat.

Comment: I Think I am not getting values of longi. And lati in getAddress funtion thats why it shows "No Value" Toast or app crashes if i remove If else from the function.

Answer (score 0):

The actual function is `getFromLocation(double latitude, double longitude, int maxResults)`. You are passing `longitude` in place of `latitude` and `latitude` in place of `longitude`. Try changing this line:

```
addresses = geocode.getFromLocation(longitude, latitude, 1);
```

to this:

```
addresses = geocode.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
```

And also add null and size check to array before accessing it to avoid `NullPointerException` and `IndexOutOfBoundException` as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)) says it can return null array

```
if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
    String Addres_ = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    String Country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
    String City = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

    adr.setText(Addres_);
    cty.setText(City);
    ctry.setText(Country);
} else {
    // Reset fields here
}
```